# right mysql indexes to reduce time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_FAB;
CREATE TEMPORARY table TEMP_FAB
(
  SELECT f.NAME, f.ID_FAB, f.COLOR          
  FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM `FAB` f ORDER BY f.TIME_MILIS DESC) f
  GROUP BY f.ID_FAB
);

/*very long run*/
SELECT h.ID as 'ID_HUMAN', h.DATE as 'NEXT_DATE',
    t.ID_MAN, 
    a.ID_FAB,   
      tf.NAME as 'FAB_NAME'
FROM `POOL` h 
INNER JOIN `TOTALS` t ON h.ID=t.ID_HUMAN
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, ID_FAB FROM `MAN` ORDER BY `TIME_MILIS` DESC) a ON t.ID_MAN=a.ID
INNER JOIN `TEMP_FAB` tf ON a.ID_FAB=tf.ID_FAB
WHERE     
    h.DATE>=1420070400000 AND 
    h.DATE<=1452267460041
GROUP BY h.ID;
```

I created these indexes but runtime is reduced just by 20%:

```
CREATE INDEX DATE ON POOL (DATE);
CREATE INDEX ID_HUMAN ON TOTALS (ID_HUMAN);
CREATE INDEX TIME_MILIS ON MAN (TIME_MILIS);
CREATE INDEX ID ON MAN (ID);
CREATE INDEX ID_FAB ON MAN (ID_FAB);
CREATE INDEX ID_MAN ON TOTALS (ID_MAN);
```

What should I do to reduce time more?

EDIT: I found out that this query "INNER JOIN `TEMP_FAB` tf ON a.ID_FAB=tf.ID_FAB" is running very long.

Comment: Show the EXPLAIN for the above, and CREATE statements for all relevant tables.

Comment: The definition of `TEMP_FAB` isn't coherent because it has columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  These return values indeterminate matching rows.  This is equally true for your outer query as well.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will google it how to correct it. Btw I added (INDEX ID_FAB(ID_FAB)) for temporary table and it reduced query time by 90%.